# How to assign real and imaginary parts of complex variables in C

Tags: c, complex-numbers

Using the complex number type of the C99 standard, how does one assign the real and imaginary parts of a variable individually? I found the GNU extension __real__ and __imag__ will do it, as in the following example program. But this isn't portable or standard. How can one do this portably?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>

int
main()
{
  complex double z;

  __real__ z = 3.0;
  __imag__ z = 2.0;

  fprintf(stderr, "z = %f + i %f\n", creal(z), cimag(z));

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C 2018 6.2.5 13 implies we can treat complex number as an array of two elements:

> Each complex type has the same representation and alignment requirements as an array type containing exactly two elements of the corresponding real type; the first element is equal to the real part, and the second element to the imaginary part, of the complex number.

This is crude wording, at odds with the explicitly stated aliasing rules in 6.5 7, but the standard is imperfect, and footnotes 41 and 49, about integers and pointers, suggest such statements about representation and alignment are supposed to allow some use of one view of the object for another in spite of the rules in 6.5 7. If so, we can define macros:

```
#define Re(x)   (_Generic((x), \
    complex float       : ((float *)       &(x)), \
    complex double      : ((double *)      &(x)), \
    complex long double : ((long double *) &(x)))[0])

#define Im(x)   (_Generic((x), \
    complex float       : ((float *)       &(x)), \
    complex double      : ((double *)      &(x)), \
    complex long double : ((long double *) &(x)))[1])
```

after which `Re(x)` and `Im(x)`, when given a complex object, produce an lvalue for the real or imaginary part. So we can assign them:

```
Re(x) = 3;
Im(x) = 4;
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can one do this portably?

It's just... addition:

```
z = 3.0;
z += I * 2.0;
```

You could first zero the imaginary part, if you want to:

```
z = creal(z) + I * 2.0;
```

> how does one assign the real and imaginary parts of a variable
> individually?

```
// assign real
z = new_value + I * cimag(z);
// assign imaginary 
z = creal(z) + I * new_value;
```

One could prefer `_Imaginary_I` or `CMPLXF` macros over `I`.

Comment: "_One could prefer `_Imaginary_I` or "_... what else? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I found another possible solution. The code below assumes that complex double is bit-equivalent to double[2] (which I think is correct but would appreciate a verification!). I think the solution below may be more efficient since it doesn't involve an extra addition operation for each assignment (as does KamilCuk's solution).

If anyone can verify this is will be portable to all platforms, I would appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>

#define SET_REAL(z, x) ( *((double *) &(z)) = (x) )
#define SET_IMAG(z, x) ( *(((double *) &(z)) + 1) = (x) )

int
main()
{
  complex double z;

  SET_REAL(z, 3.0);
  SET_IMAG(z, 2.0);

  fprintf(stderr, "z = %f + i %f\n", creal(z), cimag(z));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is just wrong - it's breaking strict aliasing. And no, it's not "more efficient", (in my opinion, it will be less efficient, cause it may be disallowing some compiler optimizations). [Compilers are smart enough](https://godbolt.org/z/9Tba4E) and C language is not 1:1 to assembly.

Comment: @KamilCuk: It does not break strict aliasing because C 2018 (and earlier) 6.2.5 13 says “Each complex type has the same representation and alignment requirements as an array type containing exactly two elements of the corresponding real type; the first element is equal to the real part, and the second element to the imaginary part, of the complex number,” and we know from footnote 41 to an earlier paragraph about integers that this phrasing about representation and alignment is intended to imply interchangeability.

Comment: Your macros would be more intuitively defined as, say, `#define Re(x) (((double *) &(x))[0])` and `#define Im(x) (((double *) &(x))[1])`, after which you could simply write `Re(x) = 3;` and `Im(x) = 4;`.

Comment: @Eric: thank you I like your solution better. If you make an answer, I will give you the credit.

Comment: This may need a separate question, but do you think there is a way to define a macro like your Re/Im which will work for double, float, and long double? Like inside the macro could I check for the type of the input variable to determine how to cast the pointer? Something like: #if type(z) == float then (((float *) &(x))[0])

Comment: Its mind boggling to me that something like this wasn't included in the C99 standard when complex numbers were introduced.